# MySQL Workbench to preserve original SQL formatting

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am an MSSQL programmer for almost 2 decades already, now I started developing in MySQL and I am using MySQL Workbench. I face difficulty recognizing my own queries when I save them as views or stored procedures. To illustrate this if I create a simple view like this:

```
select 1 
AS 
test
```

and edit it again it will come up as:

```
select 1 AS `test`
```

I don't want this! I want the query to remain as I wrote it, is this possible to configure?

The only one that I could find is Reformat DDL for Views, but that doesn't help at all.

Comment: No, it’s not possible. They’re stored in the database however they are and shown however they are, not as you write them in.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to mysql workbench, but to mysql itself, see : 
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62308

Comment: Thanks, for answering this so fast, OK will try to save queries somewhere else then

Comment: Last but not least, consider storing the view definition, stored procedures, and UDF in a source control system (svn, git, etc.) outside the database. Versioning is critical for application stability.